# How to monitor the creation and exit events of all child processes recursively of a specific process in Linux (centos)

Tags: linux, exit-code, python-watchdog, bcc-bpf, process-monitoring

Suppose I specify a process (known process id), how do I monitor the creation and exit events of all recursive child processes of this process, including:

- When the child process was created
- The exit time of the child process
- The exit code of the child process
- The event that the child process is killed

I have already tried:

1. bcc-tools: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc, it provides tools like execsnoop and exitsnoop, but it requires Linux 4.1 and above. Because the cluster I hold cannot easily upgrade the kernel (the current kernel is 3.10), so I gave up on this method
2. perf-tools: https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools, it provides execsnoop works on Linux-3.10, but it does not provide the exitsnoop to monitor the exit events of process
3. python watchdog to watch `/proc/pid/*`: I tried to use Python watchdog to monitor the event of file change in `/proc/{pid}/task/{pid}/children`. I want to know if the process(with {pid}) creates a subprocess(with {sub_pid}) so that I can watch the file change of /proc/{sub_pid}/*. But I found that the Python watchdog is unable to detect file changes of `/proc/{pid}/task/{pid}/children`.
4. strace: strace has an impact on the performance of the monitored process, so I also gave up this method

So I wonder if there is any other way to monitor the process creation and exit events in Linux(3.10) without performance impact on the monitored process